# Why does Ads (Rewarded Video or Intersititals) in games skips when you press home and tap on games icon in Android?

Tags: android, unity-ads

I have stumbled upon an issue wherein Android when I play **rewarded video** or any interstitial and do following steps:

1. In the middle of a video Ad I press the home button
2. Resume back from background tray the ad plays where I left off.

BUT if,

1. In the middle of a video Ad I press the home button
2. Tap on the game **icon** to resume back then it skips the ad and game continues without getting any reward.

I thought this might be anything specific to my code but then I tried playing many other games including **Mr. Bullet**, **Hospital Inc**, **Idle LumberJack**, **Super Salon** and the list goes on and all had the same issue.

Is this some android thing? As for iOS, this doesn't happen.
I would like to have some information on why this happens and can we prevent it from happening.
I am using Unity 3D for my game development and AppLovin MAX for ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only begin to guess as to the cause, but I think what you’re really looking for is a solution. I would recommend going through AppLovin’s support guide, which recommends enabling verbose logging to see if there’s anything amiss:

https://monetization-support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/236114328-How-do-I-enable-verbose-logging-in-AppLovin-s-SDK-

> Unity (MAX Plugin)
>
> If you are on the AppLovin MAX Unity Plugin,
> verbose logging can be toggled directly on the MaxSdk class.

```
MaxSdk.SetVerboseLogging(true);
```

Then check your logcat to find out what’s going on.

They also have a contact form:

https://monetization-support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

As for the cause, my first guess is maybe the icon is bound specifically to launch the Unity activity, not whatever activity was in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you, I am in contact with Applovin support but thank you for the detailed overview.   In case I found the exact answer I'll post that otherwise, I'll mark your answer.